# Setting rounded corners to an an button while using an imange as the background - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, image, button

I am trying to get rounded corners on my button. 
I am using a selector xml to define different button states but the grass.png image seems to be overriding other attributes.

My resulting button is just square.

Any suggestions on how to have a button with rounded corners while using a .png as the background?

selector_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/grass">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/grass">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Button style:

```
<style name="button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonText</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_button</item>
</style>
```

layout.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/newGame_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/newGame_button"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:onClick="NewGameClicked"
        style="@style/button"/>
```

------EDIT------------ Attempting Trevor Harts solution.

The background did have rounded buttons but my grass image doesn't fill the button and there is no longer any text on the button.

button_default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"/>
 </shape>
```

activity_main.xml

```
        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/newGame_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/newGame_button"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:onClick="NewGameClicked"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_default"
        android:src="@drawable/grass" />
```

Comment: Did what I recommend work?

Comment: I did not work. The button still came out square.

Comment: Can you update your code to what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

RoundedButton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@color/Green" />
  <corners 
      android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
      android:topRightRadius="5dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Your layout:

```
<ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/RoundedButton"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonImage"
            android:layout_width="78.0dp"
            android:layout_height="78.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

If you need to programmatically do this, you can do so like this:

```
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.RoundedButton);
```